# How to correctly deal with time saving on server and client side

Tags: java, mongodb, time, timezone, utc

I have read a lot about time ( incremental time , observed time, offset, timezones...)
Now I'm developing a Backend Architecture with Spring and it comes to the point where i have to fit it all together. Clients send and receive JSONs with Timestamps and values and I can decide how the Syntax should be. I'm not shure if the constellation is right the way I planed it so I would be happy if you correct me in necessary points.

**First: How I understand the basic concept.**

Mantra: Always work with utc time.

Format : iso8601 
            YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00)
            or
            1997-07-16T20:20:30.45Z

TimeZone: eg "Europe/Berlin" 
          This is the id for timezone database where the specific rules for the 
          zones are defined ( DST offset .. ).

Offset: Tells you the positive or negative offset to the utc time.

**What I planned:** 
In my case it is possible that the data was sampled within diefferent timezones. It's also porrible that a timezone is changed during the sampling process.

So I want to store the data as follows in my mongodb:

```
 "TimeStamp": {
                            "StartTime":  "1997-07-16T20:20:30.45Z",
                            "EndTime":  "1997-07-16T20:20:30.45Z",
                            "StartTimeZone":"Europe/Berlin",
                            "EndTimeZone":"Europe/Berlin",
                            "StartTimeOffset": +7,
                            "EndTimeOffset" : +7
                        }
```

The client can choose an interval from within the data will be returned. The interval has also to be defined as UTC iso format without offset. As far as I know with the UTC format I can do $lte and $gte operations on the date to filter the interval.
So the client receives a JSOnArray with mupltiple JSOnObjects. Each Object has a value and a TimeStamp Object. With using the TimeZone one can have a look how the offset was at the time when the data was sampled so I don't have to add offset information and so one can calculate the local time of the user. But what if the offset changes. I guess it makes sense also to store the offset for that so so one can reconstruct also "old" timezone rules.
Do you think this is a good solution or is there something I forgot/misunderstood/can be done more efficient

Comment: Your approach sounds sound to me. Java works best with offsets of two-digit hours, colon and minutes, for example `+07:00`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Question is rather confused.

If you have a moment in UTC, you know the offset-from-UTC is zero, so you do not care about further time zone information.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;      // Capture the current moment as seen in UTC (an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds).
String output = instant.toString() ;   // Generate text representing this moment in UTC in standard ISO 8601 format. The `Z` on end means UTC (an offset of zero), and is pronounced "Zulu".
```

If someone wants to see that moment through the wall-clock time used in Germany, they can apply a `ZoneId` to produce a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZoneId zBerlin = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Berlin" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtBerlin = instant.atZone( zBerlin ) ;
```

If someone wants to see that moment through the wall-clock time used in Japan, ditto.

```
ZoneId zTokyo = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ; 
ZonedDateTime zdtTokyo = instant.atZone( zTokyo ) ;
```

If someone wants to see that moment through the wall-clock time used in Québec, ditto.

```
ZoneId zMontréal = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ; 
ZonedDateTime zdtMontréal = instant.atZone( zMontréal ) ;
```

All of these (`instant`, `zdtBerlin`, `zdtTokyo`, `zdtMontréal`) all represent the very same simultaneous moment, the same point on the timeline. Only the wall-clock time is different. Imagine a conference call with participants in each of these regions. They all experience the same moment, but when they look up at the clock hanging on their respective wall, they each see a different reading.

> TimeZone: eg "Europe/Berlin" This is the id for timezone database where the specific rules for the zones are defined ( DST offset .. ).
>
> Offset: Tells you the positive or negative offset to the utc time.

Be clear on the meaning of zone and offset:

- Offset-from-UTC is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds. Nothing more. For example, `-07:00`.
- A time zone is *much* more. A time zone is a history of past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region. For example, in a place with politicians crazy enough to have adopted [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time), their offset-from-UTC changes twice per year, jumping a head an hour, and then falling back an hour. DST does not bend time in an [Einstein/Relativity sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime), DST merely plays silly games with wall-clock time.

> data was sampled within different timezones

You do not care. If you have a moment captured in UTC, that is all you need.

> It's also porrible that a timezone is changed during the sampling process.

Again… You do not care. If you have a moment captured in UTC, that is all you need.

> So I want to store the data as follows in my mongodb:

```json
 "TimeStamp": {
    "StartTime":  "1997-07-16T20:20:30.45Z",
    "EndTime":  "1997-07-16T20:20:30.45Z",
    "StartTimeZone":"Europe/Berlin",
    "EndTimeZone":"Europe/Berlin",
    "StartTimeOffset": +7,
    "EndTimeOffset" : +7
}
```

No, much too much. The last four lines are redundant and possibly confusing. All you need is:

```json
 "TimeStamp": {
    "StartTime":  "1997-07-16T20:20:30.45Z",
    "EndTime":  "1997-07-16T20:20:30.45Z"
}
```

By the way, the term `timestamp` usually means a specific moment, not a span of time. I suggest a better name such as `timespan`.

```json
 "TimeSpan": {
    "StartTime":  "1997-07-16T20:20:30.45Z",
    "EndTime":  "1997-07-16T20:20:30.45Z"
}
```

By the way, in your examples the start time equals the end time. Perhaps you made a mistake when posting.

> With using the TimeZone one can have a look how the offset was at the time when the data was sampled so I don't have to add offset information

You do not need additional offset information. The `Z` on the end of the first two lines tells you everything you need to know. The `Z`, pronounced "Zulu", means UTC, an offset of zero.

```
String input = "1997-07-16T20:20:30.45Z" ;    // The `Z` = UTC, an offset of zero.
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input ) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;     // Same moment, different wall-clock time.
```

> so one can calculate the local time of the user

Apparently the word "user" here is a poor choice of terms. You mean the person collecting the data, not the person receiving the data. So you want to remember the time zone in which the data was collected.

So bundle the name of the time zone in which the data sample or instrument reading was collected.

```json
 "TimeSpan": {
    "StartTime":  "1997-07-16T20:20:30.45Z",
    "EndTime":  "1997-07-16T20:20:30.45Z"
    "SampleTimeZone": "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

When you want to localize a moment, all you need is a moment (an `Instant`) and a time zone (a `ZoneId`). From that you can *generate* a string using the wall-clock time of that zone.

```
String startInput = …  // Pull "StartTime" element from JSON.
String zoneName = …  // Pull "SampleTimeZone" from JSON.
Instant instant = Instant.parse( startInput ) ;  // "1997-07-16T20:20:30.45Z"
ZoneName zone = ZoneId.of( zoneName ) ;  //  "Europe/Berlin" 
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( zone ) ;
String output = zdt.toString() ;    // Or use a `DateTimeFormatter`.
```

> Do you think this is a good solution

No. You were confused about UTC, time zone, and offset-from-UTC somehow being unrelated. But they are all connected. UTC is The One True time. Some places used an offset to adjust for their region’s wall-clock time. A time zone is a history of those changes for that region.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation/answer. I'm sorry but I forgot to give you more input about my businesslogig. 

Story: A user collects data e.g. in germany. The timespan ( good wording, thx;) ), the local time of the day is important because I measure body activity that is related to the local day/night/sleep rythm and stuff like that. So what I planned was to let the client who watches the data e.g. from another timezone to reconstruct what day time it was when the user collected the data. I hope you know what I mean.

Comment: @medTech This is the kind of detail you need to write into your Question *before* you post, not after.

Comment: @medTech As my Answer explained, there is no need to to send the Berlin time nor the offset. Just send the name of the time zone (`Europe/Berlin`) of data collection. That time zone already knows the offset in effect at that moment. And the local wall-clock time can be constructed later by instantiating a `ZoneId` from the zone name, and instantiating a `ZonedDateTime` from the `Instant` by applying the `ZoneId`. I revamped my Answer near the bottom to address your clarification. Note the 3 elements in my suggested JSON.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention this in my question. I thought about saving the offset also to reconstruct the time in case the offset changes and I want to be able to know the old offset. But I've read that die olson db knows all the changes of the past. So thank you I'll follow your advice and work with utc timestamps

Comment: @medTech Knowing the offset changes of the past (and present and future) in that particular region is the very definition of a time zone.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, if you want to talk about a particular point in time, use `Instant`. If 2 events happen in different timezones, but at the same actual moment, their `Instant` value will be the same.

If you want to know what various clocks in that area said at that time, you need to know which timezone you are in. For example:

```
Instant now = Instant.now();  // refers to a point in time, independent of location
LocalDateTime nowHere = now.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();  // refers to "what the clocks say" at your machine's current timezone
LocalDateTime nowSomewhereElse = now.atZone(ZoneId.of("Timezone string")).toLocalDate();  // same as above, but for somewhere else.
```

The following APIs are part of Java 8 and are fully compatible with JPA and other commonly used libraries/APIs. Equivalent classes exist if you only care about the day that an event took place.

An `Instant` can also be converted to a timestamp using `instant.toEpochMilli()`, `instant.getEpochSecond()` or `instant.getNano()`.

Comment: thank you but in my case I don't have to deal how the timestamp is created. I just receive complete JSONS where the client already put in all the time information. So what i need to know is more about if the format I want to use is right and I the reconstructino process of the local time I mentioned is right

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is wrong class to use here. It cannot represent a moment, as explained in the Javadoc.